# Monitoring network traffic from Microsoft Loopback Adapter

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, loopback, network-traffic

I am getting my internet connection through a Microsoft Loopback Adapter (coming from a Virtualbox), and because of loopback implementation, you can't monitor its traffic via Perfmon or Task Manager.

I want to find out if there are any creative workarounds to bridge or route this loopback adapter traffic through some kind of interface that Perfmon CAN monitor.

For example somehow use a TAP Adapter, or some other special type of virtual network driver, or even somehow use an unused physical adapter.

PS: I know you can do some tricks to capture traffic and packet sniff through Wireshark, but I'm not after log files of packets. I want Perfmon to work (so that for example Task Manager's UL/DL or Rainmeter's graphs can display)

### [EDIT]

I didn't know Virtualbox's own virtual network adapter driver solves my problem (already had a loopback set up and was new to VB). Thanks Daniel B.

It would still be interesting to know if there are workarounds for the Loopback Adapter specifically, otherwise this question can be closed.

Comment: VirtualBox provides its own network driver though? These connections do appear in Task Manager.

Comment: I only recently started using Virtualbox (and already had my loopback adapter), didn't realize that! Thanks!